# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

Using Springboot starter app.  Everything working. Then I moved the client and server to new packages. Everything compiles, but at runtime when I run the client I get an error:  UNIMPLEMENTED Method not found.

I checked that the method is in fact implemented. When I start the Springboot app where do I confirm that the bean itself was loaded? I just see confirmation that the application is up and running but no list of loaded beans in log.

Here is my Springboot application.  All I did was move the client and server bean into a new package called example.client and example.server.   before they were in same package as spring boot com.test.MyApplication

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found:  example.GreetingService/greetingWithResponseStream
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
at  io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:434)
at  io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)



package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

GreetingService.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example;

message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}


message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}


service GreetingService {
    rpc greeting (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
    rpc greetingWithResponseStream (HelloRequest) returns (stream  HelloResponse);
  rpc greetingWithRequestStream (stream HelloRequest) returns  (HelloResponse);
rpc greetingWithRequestResponseStream (stream HelloRequest) returns  (stream HelloResponse);
```

}

```
import example.GreetingServiceOuterClass;

import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@GrpcService
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends    GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceImplBase{

@Override
public void greeting(GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest request,   StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
    GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse response =    GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse.newBuilder()
            .setGreeting("HELLO, THERE, " + request.getName())
            .build();
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();

}

@Override
public void  greetingWithResponseStream(GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
    GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse response =  GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse.newBuilder()
            .setGreeting("(Stream Response) Hello there, " + request.getName())
            .build();
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}

@Override
public StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest>  greetingWithRequestStream(StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
    return new StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest>() {
        private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onNext(GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest request) {
            nameList.add(request.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse response = GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse.newBuilder()
                    .setGreeting("(Stream Request) Hello there, " + String.join(" ", nameList))
                    .build();
            responseObserver.onNext(response);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest> greetingWithRequestResponseStream(StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
    return new StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest>() {
        private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onNext(GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest request) {
            nameList.add(request.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            nameList.stream()
                    .map(name ->  GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse.newBuilder().setGreeting("(Stream Request/Response) Hello there, " + name).build())
                    .forEach(responseObserver::onNext);
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        }
    };
}
}


package example.client;

import example.GreetingServiceGrpc;
import example.GreetingServiceOuterClass;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ManagedChannel channel =   ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost:8081")
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

        GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceBlockingStub stub =    GreetingServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest request = GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName("Steve").build();
    GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse response = stub.greeting(request);
    System.out.println(response);
}


public static class RequestStreamClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {

        new Thread(() -> {

            ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost:8081")
                    .usePlaintext()
                    .build();

            GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceStub stub = GreetingServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);

            StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest> requestStream =
                    stub.greetingWithRequestStream(new StreamObserver<GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloResponse response) {
                            System.out.println(response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                        }
                    });

            Stream.of("Steve1", "Steve2", "Steve3")
                    .map(name -> GreetingServiceOuterClass.HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).build())
                    .forEach(requestStream::onNext);
            requestStream.onCompleted();



        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);


    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same error, and renaming the package of client with same name as server in the proto files solved the issue.

Comment: See, [io/grpc/internal/ServerImpl.java#L547](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/613439c97e8ab3a62670411fd9367aa126fed2cf/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/ServerImpl.java#L547), [issues](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7263)

Comment: [java client sample](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-service-sample-client), [java server sample](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-service-pemo). [Springboot client](https://github.com/ppdouble/springboot-grpc-client-sample), [Springboot server](https://github.com/ppdouble/springboot-grpc-server-sample)

Answer (score 3):

@SpringBootApplication [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) states:

> This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring
>   @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.

And @ComponentScan [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) states:

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the
>   package of the class that declares this annotation.

This means that by default the @SpringBootApplication annotation scans all classes in the same package or below (see [the best practices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) on structuring your code in Spring Boot application).

But if you do not want to move your classes, you can import them explicitly, using the @ComponentScan or @Import annotations on the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"example.client","example.server"})
@Import(GreetingServiceImpl.class)
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```